# Parallel data (entropy) collection in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, cryptography, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to code a PRNG which adds entropy into its state. To do that, i want to use multiple entropy sources, that would collect the entropy <strike>asynchronously</strike> in parallel into buckets, and the PRNG itself would then take the data from them.

What is the best way to build such asynchronous data collection in python?

```
class EntropyBuckets(object):
    buckets = [[]] ## only an example, this should be a structure capable of working with asynchronously added data

    def get_entropy(self):
        pass
```

In essence this would be used by the PRNG. During initialization all of the entropy sources would start running asynchronously for the duration of the process. PRNG would then be able to request entropy without being blocked (due to waiting for more data).

```
class EntropySource(object):
    entropy_bucket = None # reference to a single EntropyBuckets bucket where it adds its entropy
```

This is just some random class to represent the source. It can define any methods, but the main point is it only has reference to single bucket it adds entropy into. There is no further interaction with teh parent class outside of when it gets shut down.

As for what these sources are, it can be anything from cpu temp, clocks, keyboard or mouse data, etc.

Just to reiterate, the question is only about what would be the best way to <strike>asynchronously</strike> collect data in parallel like this.

Comment: Have a look at asyncio, coroutines and greenthreads. But I think you should read Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) about how to code a class first...

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but doesn't asyncio still only execute one task at a time? My question is about parallel execution.

Comment: No, your question is about *concurrent* execution.

Comment: I really can't tell from your question if you're unsure how perform concurrent execution or unsure how to use synchronization features to safely access a shared resource during concurrent execution.

Comment: I know how to deal with the concurent execution, the question is meant mostly about what is the best way to accomplish that.